# What is the best way to add additional templates to a helm chart?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

## Background

I'm installing Elastic Search into my cluster with a helm chart with the following command:

```bash
helm -n elasticsearch upgrade --install -f values_elasticsearch.yaml  elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch
```

This allows me to override the values which is nice, but I'd also like to add an [Istio virtual service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/). Which I believe would require I add a template to the helm chart.

### Options

I've considered the following thee options, but not sure what is best practice.

1. Download the elastic search maintained helm chart and add a template for the additional yamls I need. This could create an issue when they upgrade their helm, I'm gonging to have to keep merging in their changes.
2. Add the template to a separate helm chart. I don't love this solution because I like to have one helm chart for a single namespace and application.
3. Create a helm subchart. I don't know much about these or if this is the right scenario to use them in.

So I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this or which of my options is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

helm subchart is ideal way

- You can create a helm chart and add the elasticsearch as subchart
- You can add required istio yaml files inside your template folder
- First you should run `helm dep update` then run the install/upgrade command